# Printing out string in c

Tags: c

The desired output:

```
Student 99704 exam1 97 exam2 64 exam3 61 grade C
```

But instead getting:

```
Student 991704,97,64,61,C exam1 0 exam2 4195335 exam3 &d ((null)) on class.
```

Maybe a `for` loop is needed to print out the array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void flushScanf();
int main(void)
{
#if 0
    char str[10];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%9[^\n]", str);
    flushScanf();
    printf("%s", str);
#endif
    FILE* f = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file test.dat.");
        exit(1);
    }
    ///////
    char line[65];
    char studentID[26];
    char grade[8];
    int exam1, exam2, exam3;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL){
        sscanf(line,
               "%25[^\n], %*s, %d, %d, %d, %s",
               studentID, &exam1, &exam2, &exam3, grade);
        printf("Student %s exam1 %d exam2 %d exam3 &d (%s) on class.\n",
               studentID, exam1, exam2, exam3, grade);
    }
    if (fclose(f) == EOF){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file test.dat.");
        exit(2);
    }
    return 0;
}
void flushScanf()
{
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;
}
```

Comment: Post sample input used.

Comment: @josmar  Are you sure that input data are separated with comma?

Comment: You want something like `sscanf(line, "%25[0123456789]...` else `"991704,97,64,61,C"` is the student ID or just read student ID as a number.

Comment: You are scanning with ", " but the actual input is "," with no space.

Comment: @stark That makes little difference here.  A `" "` in the scan format consumes 0 or more white-spaces.

Comment: Suggest 1) checking the response of `sscanf()` 2) Use format `" %25[0123456789] ,%*s ,%d ,%d ,%d ,%7s"`

Comment: did that now getting this:                                                                       `Student 991704, exam1 0, exam2 4195335, exam3 &d, ((null)) on class.`         @chux

Comment: Still waiting on [sample input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687433/printing-out-string-in-c?noredirect=1#comment68605441_40687433) and I doubt you did #1 of this [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687433/printing-out-string-in-c?noredirect=1#comment68605574_40687433)

Comment: Since I am getting the data from an excel sheet(grades.csv), each data will be in a cell within one row, so 5 cells total for one record. @chux

Comment: `%25[^\n]` will not stop at the first comma. Try `%25[^,]`